# C# Append text with Encoding.UTF8

Tags: c#, csv, utf-8

I have this code:

```
 using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path + kat + "/" + namec, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(namex + "," + address + "," + web + "," + email + "," + phone  + "," + linksx + "," + transport);
                            }
```

How I can append text and include Encoding.UTF8 ?

I tried this:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path + kat + "/" + namec, false, Encoding.UTF8))
```

But i got this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1501  No overload for method 'AppendText' takes 3
>   arguments visitdenmark    C:\Users\???\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\visitdenmark\visitdenmark\Form1.cs  193 Active

Comment: Not sure if I get you but the second parameter of the StreamWriter is to set whether it should append or not. You can just use the same code but set the parameter to true.

Comment: @ogomrub ok please show me, how would you append it including Encoding.UTF8 ?

Comment: I was meaning the same as @Larsupilami wrote down.
You get some unexpected character in the file, could it be that you are opening the file with a tool that is using an encoding different than UTF8?

Comment: I got the string from website visitdenmark.dk example I have this name Danhostel Rønne but wehn I store it in csv file and it looks like this Danhostel RĂ¸nne

Comment: I have very strange problem, when I set it on false everything works normal it showing name like this "Rønne" but I can't do on this way because I need to append it, so when I set it to the true then it append correctly but  showing name like this "RĂ¸nne". Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error message is correct. Claiming that `AppendText` does not take 3 arguments.

But in my optinion there is no need to leave your first approach with the `StreamWriter` aside. But in order to append the text you should change the second parameter to `true`

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path + kat + "/" + namec, true, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.WriteLine(namex + "," + address + "," + web + "," + email + "," + phone + "," + linksx + "," + transport);
}
```

Comment: But when I set it on true I get something like this in the string Ă it does not help me

Comment: In this case most probably your input data is scambled already. Because this piece of code is handling the UTF-8 properly.

Please verify that the values of `namex`, `address` etc. are properly formatted.

Comment: I have very strange problem, when I set it on false everything works normal it showing name like this "Rønne" but I can't do on this way because I need to append it, so when I set it to the true then it append correctly but  showing name like this "RĂ¸nne". Very strange.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide a bit more information about the context which is surrounding the scenario. I assume that something else is interfering.